# Execute logic before any Intent starts. Decide which Intent should start

Tags: android, android-intent

I wanna to be able to execute some code (logic) as soon the application starts before any Intent starts. For example..I wanna to decide which of a list of Intents should start. Is this possible in Android ? For example.
I have intent Login and intent MainWindow.
If the user is not already logged in I wanna to show the login intent..otherwise the MainWindow.

Comment: Please explain more of what you want to do. Provide an example. Your question isn't detailed or clear enough for anyone to spend any effort on trying to answer it. We aren't mind-readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this functionality is achived using your Login `Activity`. Check in `onCreate` method if user needs authorization, and if not - start MainWindow immediately (and `finish()` Login `Activity`).

Comment: I tryed this but even if i call finish() the login activity is loaded shown for 50 milliseconds and after that only disappears.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro Just do not use `setContentView()` in such case